# eternicode date picker - dynamically change language

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have installed [eternicode bootstrap date picker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?#sandbox) to a test form. This is working well.

I am now wanting to dynamically change the language of the date picker when the user changes a language select list on the form.

The exact operation is show [here](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?#sandbox), on the eternicode sand box. If the user changes the language select list, the language of the date picker changes to the selected language without a page re-fresh.

I have tried to get this to work on my form, but cannot figure out how to get this to work on my form without a page re-fresh. I have looked at the source code, but could not find it - maybe b/c I am not so good at javascript.

I have installed the language files for the eternicode bootstrap date picker to the test form.

Here is the relevant select list code that I have:

```
<select name="language_code" id="id_language_code" >
    <option value="ar">Arabic - العربية</option>
    <option value="en-GB">English (UK) - English (UK)‎</option>
    <option value="en" selected="selected">English (US)</option>
    <option value="fr-CA">French (Canada) - français (Canada)‎</option>
    <option value="fr">French (France) - français (France)‎</option>
    <option value="de">German - Deutsch</option>
    <option value="it">Italian - italiano</option>
    <option value="pl">Polish - polski</option>
    <option value="pt-BR">Portuguese (Brazil) - português (Brasil)‎</option>
    <option value="pt">Portuguese (Portugal) - português (Portugal)‎</option>
    <option value="ru">Russian - pусский</option>
    <option value="es">Spanish (Spain) - español (España)‎</option>
</select>
```

Here is the javascript code I have to add the date picker to my text field on my form:

```
    $( "#id_test_finish_date" ).datepicker({

        autoclose: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        clearBtn: true,
        endDate: '01/2900',
        format: 'mm/yyyy',
        language: 'en',
        minViewMode: 1,
        startView: 2,
        startDate: '01/1965',

    }).attr('readonly','readonly');
```

**I am hoping that someone smarter than me can show me how to get this working.**

Comment: Pass the data to javascript, save it in a variable, and have language property be dependant on that variable.

Comment: I understand the concept, but not the actual methodology. Show me how.

Comment: How would you pass in any data to javascript?

Comment: Well, that is what I am asking advice on how to do that! That is what you suggested in your previous comment.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.google.com I'm trying to help you how to find the answers and learn, instead of copy and paste code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pc9barL0/

**JQ:**

```
//datepicker localization files:
//https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/tree/master/js/locales

//how to localize plugin
//http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/i18n.html

//required files
//on the left side JSFIDDLE click on the External Resources  to see the required files

$( "#id_test_finish_date" ).datepicker({
    autoclose: true,    
    clearBtn: true,
    endDate: '01/01/2900',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    startDate: '01/01/1965'} 
).attr('readonly','readonly');


$( "#id_language_code" ).change(function() {
     $element=$( "#id_test_finish_date" );

     $element.datepicker('remove');
     $element.datepicker({language: $( this ).val()});
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<select name="language_code" id="id_language_code" >
    <option value="ar">Arabic - العربية</option>    
    <option value="en" selected="selected">English (US)</option>    
    <option value="fr">French (France) - français (France)‎</option>
    <option value="ru">Russian - pусский</option>    
    <option value="rs">Serbian - српски</option>    
</select>
<br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="id_test_finish_date" />
```